# Is the sentence "It is removed" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, passive-voice

There is another form of the same sentence — "It has been removed".

But in the sentence "It is removed," the last word is an adjective so I believe it is correct as well. Am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*It is removed* is grammatically correct, but is not something people normally say. It sounds quite stilted.

The only context I can think of would be as a reply from a "right hand man" to his boss, if the right hand man was particularly well spoken:

> Boss: This room is too cluttered. Remove this obelisk.
>
> RHM: Yes sir.
>
> (RHM gestures to minions. Minions remove the obelisk.)
>
> RHM: It is removed.

A much more common idiom is *it is [far] removed from X* which implies the thing that *it* refers to is [very] different to *X*.

E.g.

> This chaise longue is far removed from the stools of your hovel, eh?

Answer (score 0):

To my ears, "It is removed" strongly sounds like you're saying "It is regularly/habitually removed", i.e. expressing an action that generally occurs rather than the state of something that has been removed on a single occasion.

For the meaning you're interested in, I would stick to "It has been removed".

Comment: Not really.  And if you change the adjective, even less so; "It is gone" sounds fine.

Comment: NB "remove" and "go" are different types of verb.

Answer (score 0):

"It is removed" would be a description of the event as it is happening. "It was removed" matches a description of something was removed some other time than now.

> Where is my chair?! / It was removed.
>
> I don't like that. Get it out of here. / It is removed.

"It has been removed" is similar to "it was removed".